# Entity Framework migration AddColumn(), followed by Sql(@"Update of that column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Given this migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.ClientData", "ExFirstName", c => c.String(maxLength: 2));
    Sql(@"UPDATE [ClientData]
            SET ExFirstName = LEFT(EX,2)
          WHERE RandomEX = 0
            AND LEN(EX) = 8");
```

Then I generate migrations as sql script to give to dba

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientData] ADD [ExFirstName] [nvarchar](2)
UPDATE [ClientData]
                SET ExFirstName = LEFT(EX,2)
              WHERE RandomEX = 0
                AND LEN(EX) = 8
```

Then when run it fails on the UPDATE because the ALTER TABLE isn't followed by a "GO".

Here is the exact error:
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server MYSERVER\SQLSVR, Line 34
Invalid column name 'ExFirstName'.

I confirmed that by running above sql in ssms w/ and w/o the GO.

When running the migrations in code:

```
      if (RunEFMigrations(dataSource))
    {
        var efConfiguration = new NEX.Data.Migrations.Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(efConfiguration);
        migrator.Update();
    }
```

The migrations work just fine.

Baring splitting the above migration and some of my other 80+ EF migrations up into two EF migrations do I have other options either in the EF configuration or within SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think there is any ready-made solution since MSSS `Name Resolution` is designed to behave like this. Check this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/15/sql-server-deferred-name-resolution/

Comment: I think `AddColumn` can be tweaked so that it generates a `Go` command at the end of each call. But you have to turn this feature  off when you don't want generate scripts for you DBA (i.e. you want to work locally). If you want I can provide you this (somehow nasty but working) solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing the answer from [Test Column exists, Add Column, and Update Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761933/test-column-exists-add-column-and-update-column)

by wrapping the update statement with EXEC sp_executesql

```
   EXEC sp_executesql
        N'UPDATE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] SET [IsDownloadable] = 1 WHERE [Ref] IS NOT NULL'
```