# Check multi columns existency before adding those columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to add some columns dynamically in a table (`TargetTable`). Before doing that I need to check whether the columns are already exists in `TargetTable`. If they do not exist, then that column will be added, otherwise not.

This is not for fixed column. These columns are storing at `SourceTable`'s rows.

How do I check the existence of each column before adding in the `TargetTable`?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with - [checking if the column exists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/133031/1048425), or [adding a column dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2761933/1048425)?

Comment: checking if the column exists

Comment: simple column existence is covered already, and extending that to refer to data in your sourcetable will be join/filter. Use any means (count rows returned, cursor through results) to decide what to add... otherwise your question is incomplete..