# IF EXISTS then Update else do Nothing - SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which assigns roles to particular users. I am doing mass update to this table where in I am end dating some users previous roles and after that is completed assigning them new roles by inserting into this table.

I am doing both these actions separately. For my first action my code goes like this.

```
UPDATE userrolelist
SET effectiveend = '2016-01-20 00:00:00.000'
where userid IN ('150920','160847','160848','160849')
and roleid = '1037' and effectiveend IS NULL
```

This works if there is no end date assigned to that role but if there is an end date for even 1 user the whole update statement terminates. I want to use an IF EXISTS statement to first check if an end date for this user and this role exists if not then do the update else do nothing.

Inserting is similar. I am running a 100 inserts based on the user that need to have new roles. Now again when i run these insert statements if it finds any duplicates it errors out.

```
Insert into userrolelist (Userid, Roleid, IsDefault, EffectiveStart, 
EffectiveEnd, Clientid, LastmodifiedUserId, LastmodifiedTimestamp)
Values 
(161514,1011,1,'2016-01-21 00:00:00.001',Null,16785,0,'2016-01-21 
00:00:00.001')
```

Table structure:

[image: Table Structure]

Comment: That seems very strange. The fact that you have records that doesn't fit the conditions in the where clause should not effect the update of the records that does fit.

Comment: Yeah - please clarify what records you WANT to update.  The code you posted should work.  What are you trying to accomplish (in detail)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled- So basically as I said I am trying to MASS Update / End date roles and then insert new roles from some users. 

Now the issue here is for some users HR might have gone in from the FRONT END and manually done the action. So when I try to run the UPDATE AND THEN THE INSERT SCRIPT and if matches some employees who have already been changed then the whole UPDATE and INSERT statement terminates.

Comment: Are you getting an error when it terminates?   What is the error message?

Comment: Update or insert is the designed use case for the MERGE statement (sometimes referred to as "upsert"). This was added to SQL Server for 2008 edition so it is available to you. (See MS docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

Comment: I think this might answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2761933/5889360

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood correctly your question, but maybe you can try this:

```
UPDATE A SET EFFECTIVEEND = '2016-01-20 00:00:00.000'
FROM USERROLELIST A
WHERE A.USERID IN ('150920','160847','160848','160849')
AND A.ROLEID = '1037' AND A.EFFECTIVEEND IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM USERROLELIST B WHERE B.USERID IN ('150920','160847','160848','160849') AND B.effectiveend IS NOT NULL) ;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE USERROLELIST  (USERID INT, ROLEID INT, EFFECTIVEEND DATETIME);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (150920, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160847, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160848, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160849, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160850, 1037,NULL);
```

Output:

```
USERID  ROLEID  EFFECTIVEEND
150920  1037    2016-01-20 00:00:00.000
160847  1037    2016-01-20 00:00:00.000
160848  1037    2016-01-20 00:00:00.000
160849  1037    2016-01-20 00:00:00.000
160850  1037    NULL
```

Sample2:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE USERROLELIST
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (150920, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160847, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160848, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160849, 1037,NULL);
INSERT INTO USERROLELIST VALUES (160850, 1037,NULL);
UPDATE USERROLELIST SET EFFECTIVEEND='20160119' WHERE USERID=150920;
```

Output:

```
USERID  ROLEID  EFFECTIVEEND
150920  1037    2016-01-19 00:00:00.000
160847  1037    NULL
160848  1037    NULL
160849  1037    NULL
160850  1037    NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure it should use an IN in the NOT EXISTS query? Why not link it to A.USERID instead?

Comment: @lukStorms  I think he wants not to do update if at least one userid has not value in effectiveend.  I added sample data and output in answer

Comment: "at least one". Ok, makes sense then.

Comment: @lukStorms   well, otherwise, simple update (as the original one he posted) would be sufficient.

Comment: @etsa - So i want to do an update and insert . So basically for update because there are 100 updates being done at the same time there might be some record which might have manually been updated. So i still want the code to run and update the rest and not break. 
Because currently if there is any record already updated then the update statement breaks and does not continue for the other 99 records and same goes for the insert. 
Insert and if value already exists skip it / do nothing and still do the remaining inserts.

Comment: I have basically figured out the update statement. The insert statement still remains a challenge for me though.

Comment: I didn't understand very well what you want to do for INSERT.  Give a look if MERGE command can help you.